# Visual Studio's Developer License duals as a personal license?

Tags: visual-studio

I can be completely wrong but I vaguely remember hearing from a podcast that according to Visual Studio's license, a developer who works with Visual Studio professionally at their work place automatically has the license to use it in their personal life. That means a developer may not have to pay for Visual Studio to legally use/own it.

Again, I can be completely wrong but if I'm right, can someone confirm with a source?

Comment: You *don't* automatically get a second license "for home use", but VS licenses are [per-user](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350). If you have a VS license to use on your work machine, it is still valid on your home machine, so long as you are the sole user of that software.

Comment: @Phoshi That looks like the right Answer to me :)

Comment: @BrianDHall I think so, but I'm in software, not law, and licensing is really more of a law thing. I wouldn't want to state it with any authority, but I can't read the licensing stuff any other way.

Comment: @Phoshi Fair enough! +1 for the wisdom to know when you aren't qualified to say authoritatively :)

Comment: I'd be careful about using a VS license provided by your workplace for personal use though, since your employer might (probably) has a clause in your contract that either forbids it or says that anything you create with their property or supplies automatically becomes property of the company.

Comment: If you are that worried you should be using `Visual Studio Express` a free version of Visual Studio exactly for this type of home use.  As pointed out before you don't magically get multiple licenses.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is [about] details to be asked about at Microsoft support forums.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to this whitepaper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350), a user with an MSDN license can use the software on any number of computers. Both MSDN and Visual Studio licences operate on a per-user basis.

The whitepaper provides the following example:

> A developer with an MSDN subscription uses MSDN software at work during the day, but occasionally needs to develop at home as well, using a different computer. Under the MSDN license, there is no difference between a PC at work and a home PC; the home PC is just another device on which the developer is entitled use the MSDN software.

However, [as user1100269 pointed out in the comments](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218457/visual-studios-developer-license-duals-as-a-personal-license/218466?comment433227_218457), your employer or your contract may state that anything you create with company property automatically becomes property of the company, so you may want to be careful.

Comment: And to make it into a nice legal mess, Microsoft claims that Visual Studio does not become property of your employer, Microsoft merely grants a license to use.